# How to use OR statement on multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have **four** variables in my excel sheet:

1. Geyser
2. Heater
3. Ac
4. Air cooler

I am creating a new variable in Excel sheet **geyser/heater/ac/aircooler** which is the combination of all these four variables. If there is a Yes in any one of the above-mentioned columns than the newly created variables should also have "**Yes**" otherwise it should be blank.

I know how to do that using **IF** and **OR** statement for **two** columns but I don't know how to use it for Four columns.[image]

Comment: Use `COUNTIF`.. e.g: `=IF(COUNTIF(A3:D3,"Yes"),"Yes","No")`

Comment: Cool! What if the columns are not adjacent to each other?We can only select range in countif

Comment: Then use an `=IF(OR(A3="Yes",B3="Yes",C3="Yes",D3="Yes"),"Yes","No")` construct. Obviously with non-adjacent cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can use this:

```
=IF(OR(A1:D1="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Include one OR argument per contiguous range. In case column C is not included:

```
=IF(OR(A1:B1="Yes",D1:E1="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

For older versions,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: What if the rows are not adjacent to each other?

Comment: One formula per row. Presumably you mean if the columns are not adjacent to each other. In which case, see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` like below if data is in non-adjacent cells

`=IF(OR(A2="Yes",C2="Yes",E2="Yes",H2="Yes"),"Yes","No")`